# ScrollPhysics: get position when user started dragging

Tags: flutter

I am implementing some custom `ScrollPhysics` by overriding:

```
Simulation createBallisticSimulation(ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to find out the position the user actually started dragging?

Comment: Can't you just store the first "position" in temp variable?

Comment: Which one is the first?